# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 1802) with webView

Tags: android

I am facing an question that I don't know how to solve it.I guess it may relate to then webView.Can some one help me? Thanks very much.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 1802)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:845)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:836)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:144)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:197)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:237)
at android.webkit.WebViewDatabaseClassic.getUsernamePassword(WebViewDatabaseClassic.java:388)
at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.handleMessage(BrowserFrame.java:516)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:973)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Please provide some sample code where your error occurs, else it might be hard to help you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! With only the stack trace, it is nearly impossible for us to find out what the problem is. Please create a [mcve] and [edit] it into your question.

Comment: It is pretty difficult to come up with a solution without any code, add the related code. Also make sure you are not accessing database on multiple threads. This Exception is usually thrown when multiple threads are accessing the database at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser.But I am really don`t know what was caused it.I  run my app in my phone,it works ok.But when I release my app in store,I get a lot of exception like this.